Make a female to female SCART PCB
I recently bought an off-brand female-to-female SCART coupler but I wasn't happy with the quality of the image. 
I thought it could be better to just make one myself with a simple PCB that links each corresponding end of the SCART sockets.
I am a beginner in working with electronics, is this simple approach enough to maintain the quality of the signal? What could I change/add to have a better result? Would I have additional problems to consider if I wanted to make a SCART switch with manual push-buttons?

Analog video signals are high speed signals that need a properly designed transmission line with correct characteristic impedance.
If the adapter you bought has poor quality, it is likely done exactly the way you thought about doing it, with a simple PCB that just wires the corresponding pins together and call that a product.
The proper aporoach is to have a properly designed PCB which basically to the signal looks like a 75 ohm coaxial cable. You need to design the board with correct track width and PCB layer height, and likely a simple 1.6mm 2 layer board can't provide you with proper 75 ohm characteristic impedance.
As the SD video is only up to 6 MHz or so in bandwidth, if the tracks are very short then it may still be adequate.
Please note that there are also varying quality and types of Scart cables. Cheap ones just use random wires and may not connect all pins you need for RGB. Better ones use actual quality coaxial cable with 75 ohm impedance for wiring the video signals properly. Your bad quality may just be due to using a poor cable and the extender box is not the source of the problem you see in the picture quality.
Some cables lack the RGB wiring so even if you think you are looking at the original quality RGB, the cable only gives you degraded quality composite, or your TV is not set to use the RGB even if available, as it may need to be separately switched to expect RGB.
And yes, looping sensitive analog video signals through push buttons and switches will further make impedance mismatches and causes signal reflections.

With a PCB I shouldn't worry about interference or is just more important in general to have the correct impedance first?

@EliaB On a PCB you can always use shielding techniques that prevent signals from coupling to each other. But the connector itself just has bare metal contacts, so it won't be shielded or correct impedance anyway. The PCB may not matter much as it's only a small part of the whole system.

Ok, I think I have a better idea of what the problems are, thank you for your time
